# Why windows user affects how built python application calls pyside/pyqt paintEvent?

Tags: python, pyqt4, pyside, cx-freeze

I've built python 3.3 application using pyqt4 and cx_freeze under windows user 'user1'.

If I run exe as windows 'user1' everything works.
If I run exe as windows 'user2' buttons in app are in wrong positions. I've figured out that widgets paintEvent is not being called (that's where i position buttons - don't ask why :)).

Any ideas why paintEvent method would be called differently just because different windows user is running exe?

Thank you for any insight!

UPDATE:

I seems that a single line is the problem. Take a look at commented out line in init method of MainWindow class (test3.py). At the bottom I attached images showing what happens for different windows users running compiled exe if this line (un)commented.

**Why is this happening?**

test3.py code to recreate the problem:

```
from PyQt4 import QtGui as pqg
from PyQt4 import QtCore as pqc
import sys
import pyqtgraph.opengl as gl
from pyqtgraph.opengl.shaders import *
import numpy as np

class AnimWidgBase(pqg.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AnimWidgBase, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # Create 3D graphics widget
        self.model_view = GLView()

        # Create layout and add widgets
        self.create_layout()

    def create_layout(self):
        vbox = pqg.QVBoxLayout()
        vbox.addWidget(self.model_view)
        self.setLayout(vbox)

class GLView(gl.GLViewWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(GLView, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setSizePolicy(pqg.QSizePolicy.Expanding, pqg.QSizePolicy.Expanding)
        self.default_width = 500
        self.default_height = 500
        self.setMinimumSize(pqc.QSize(self.default_width, self.default_height))

    def paintGL(self, *args, **kwargs):
        gl.GLViewWidget.paintGL(self, *args, **kwargs)

        #for testing
        self.loc=np.array([[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,3,3]])
        self.data=np.array(['1','2','3'])

        #print gcs labels
        for i in [0,1,2]:
            self.renderText(self.loc[i,0], self.loc[i,1], self.loc[i,2],self.data[i])

class GeometryWidget(AnimWidgBase):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(self.__class__, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def create_layout(self):
        super(self.__class__,self).create_layout()
        self._button = pqg.QPushButton('Test button', self)

    def paintEvent(self,event):
        # Position the button so that it moves when resizing
        window_width=self.rect().width()
        window_height=self.rect().height()
        w = 140 #this is overridden by css
        h = 33
        x = (window_width  - w)
        y = 0.2*window_height
        self._button.setGeometry(x,y,w,h)


class MainWindow(pqg.QFrame):
    """Main window of the application.
    """
    def __init__(self):
        """Constructor, builds the GUI."""
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.stacked_widget = pqg.QStackedWidget()
        self.vbox_gobal = pqg.QVBoxLayout()
        self.vbox_gobal.addWidget(self.stacked_widget)
        self.setLayout(self.vbox_gobal)

        self.load_geometry()

        # Uncomment this line to prevent GeometryWidget paintEvent being called !
        #self.stacked_widget.setContentsMargins(-10, -10, -10, -10)
        # -----------

    def load_geometry(self):
        self.geom_widg=GeometryWidget()
        self.stacked_widget.addWidget(self.geom_widg)
        self.stacked_widget.setCurrentWidget(self.geom_widg)


def main():
    app = pqg.QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.processEvents()
    main_window = MainWindow()
    app.processEvents()
    main_window.show()
    return sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Here is setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

base = None

options = {
    'build_exe': {
        'packages': ['OpenGL'],
        'includes': ['PyQt4'],

    },

}

executables = [
    Executable('test3.py', base=base)
]

setup(name='test',
      version='0.1',
      description='test for testing tests',
      options=options,
      executables=executables
      )
```

User1, offending line commented:
[image: User1, offending line commented]

User1, offending line UNcommented:
[image: User1, offending line UNcommented]

User2, offending line commented:
[image: User2, offending line commented]

User2, offending line UNcommented:
[image: User2, offending line UNcommented]

Comment: Impossible to tell what cause is from this information. Is there a problem before you have frozen the script(s)? How did you write your script(s)? Did you use Qt Designer, or do it by hand? Can you include some code in your question? Can you include a MVCE? http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve If you do some work to determine the minimal code to reproduce the problem, that would be a great first step.

Comment: I'm just trying to get some ideas where to search for the trouble. It would take me a lot of time to create MVCE so I tought to try first if anybody would recognise the problem. There are no problems when building regarding pyqt, nor there are any errors during run. It just works differently under different windows user accounts and I can't think of any reason why built application would do that.

Comment: Need a lot more detail we don't even know what types of windows (is it dialogs, main windows, etc). Or what type of application, is anything being saved to or, loaded from a file, what types of layout, what types of elements are in each widget (e.g., dropdown, qlineedit,just a single pushbutton)? Just not enough detail here! I would *start* by constructing a minimal example in pyqt that produces the problem when frozen: that is my suggestion. yes it takes a lot of time to do this...often I solve my own problems by doing it, though. I find my silly little error.

Comment: I really doubt this is a Qt issue. Probably something wrong with file permissions between the two user accounts

Comment: I did some serious updating...please take a look again. @neronet